# Flatlist doesn't add values React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

```
export class mondayExercises extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sets: [],
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.route.params?.set) {
      return {
        sets: [...state.sets, props.route.params.set],
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.sets}
            renderItem={(item) => (
              <View style={{ padding: "5%" }}>
                <View>
                  <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                      <TextInput
                        placeholder="sets"
                        keyboardType="numeric"
                        maxLength={3}
                        textAlign="center"
                        defaultValue={item.sets}<--------
                      />
                      <TextInput
                        placeholder="reps"
                        keyboardType="numeric"
                        maxLength={3}
                        textAlign="center"
                        defaultValue={item.reps}<------------
                      />
                      <TextInput
                        keyboardType="numeric"
                        maxLength={4}
                        textAlign="center"
                        defaultValue={item.weigth}<----------
                      />
                </View>
              </View>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key.toString()}
          />
</Container>
```

**Array Example**

```
Array [
  Object {
    "exerciseName": Object {
      "exerciseName": "Barbell Bench Press",
    },
    "key": 0.7455255006925475,
    "reps": 0,
    "sets": 0,
    "weigth": 0,
  },
```

Hello, I'm learning to do Faltlists in React Native right now, and I'm trying to display the items in the Array List in the Flatlist above, but none of the values display when I insert a console.log() it just says undefined in the Terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to destructure the argument to the renderItem function, as it is an object with an `item` field:

```
renderItem={({item}) => (
```

I would also recommend extracting that function out of your JSX to improve render performance.